# C passing structure to a callback function (Tizen)

Tags: c, callback, tizen

I'm writing an app for Tizen (smart watches). Can't pass a structure to a callback.
My typedef:

```
typedef struct _Health {
    ...;
    const char *data;
} health_s;
```

Declaring a structure and initializing it:

```
health_s health = {
    ...,
    .data = "steps"
};
```

Passing it to a function:

```
_app_check_and_request_permission("http://tizen.org/privilege/healthinfo", &health);
```

Getting and checking if the struct address passed well:

```
void _app_check_and_request_permission(const char *privilege, void *user_data)
{
    health_s *p_health = user_data;
    dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "Health data: %s", p_health->data);
    ...
```

And here I see in the log "Health data: steps". Passed well. Then I'm trying to pass user_data to a callback function

```
    ...
    ppm_request_permission(privilege, _app_request_response_cb, p_health);
}
```

From function description in Tizen docs:

```
...
* @param[in]   user_data   User specific data which will be passed to
*                          the given callback.
int ppm_request_permission(const char *privilege,
                           ppm_request_response_cb callback,
                           void *user_data);
```

Callback declaration:

```
static void _app_request_response_cb(ppm_call_cause_e cause, ppm_request_result_e result,
                             const char *privilege, void *user_data);
```

And in the callback I'm getting Health data: NULL. Tried to pass p_health->data to the callback and that's ok. The problem is with passing the whole structure.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks.
**Update:**
Checked the addresses of the passed structure in the _app_check_and_request_permission function and in the callback and they are the same. But the struct in the callback is still empty...

Comment: Normally you try to pass *a pointer to* a structure ...

Comment: @user9160119 - Did you define `health` with static storage duration, or at least are you sure that the lifetime of `health` extends to the point of callback?

Comment: @Armali No, `health` isn't defined as static. Not sure about the lifetime of `health`. Will try to figure this out somehow. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the lifetime of `health` has ended before `_app_request_response_cb` is called by the system on completion of the request. This is, for example, the case if the shown definition of `health` is contained in a function which returns before the request completes. Simple remedy: define `health` with storage class `static`.

Comment: Thanks again! You're totally right! `health` was created in `app_create` function which finished before the callback. Defined `health` as static and it works fine.